# Javascript and angularjs can't handle http.get with https url

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, https

I'm writing JavaScript and AngularJS code and i'm trying to get through a https website some JSON data.

My code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('DecisionsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://test3.diavgeia.gov.gr/luminapi/opendata/search.json?org=10599')
    .success(function (response) {$scope.decisions = response.decisions;});
});
```

and

```
  <tr ng-repeat="x in decisions | limitTo:10 ">
    <td>{{x.protocolNumber }}</td>
    <td>{{x.subject}}</td>
    <td>{{x.extraFieldValues.financialYear}}</td>
    <td>{{x.extraFieldValues.budgettype}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

A pic from error through firefox console : [image]

**If i use http website or if i download https stuff into file.json, there isn't any problem.**

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You've seen the two warnings at the bottom? Especially the second one "Cross-Origin Request Blocked"

Comment: google the terms used in last error ..... will find thousands of results

Answer (score 0):

Your request is being blocked by CORS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

If you control the server, then you can add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to allow the host you are attempting to access it from.

If you don't control the server, contact the administrators and ask them to add it, or they may have another method of access (such as JSONP).

Comment: I'm going to contact them (Is not my server) and ask from them to add it. 
Thanks a lot